# How can I change the default date output format for the date command?

Tags: command-line, date

I've used RedHat servers before and now I've just installed Ubuntu Server.

I noticed that the date format in Ubuntu logs is different from in RedHat.

When I use the `date` command it showd

```
Wed  May 30 20:00 2012
```

I want to change it to

```
2012.5.30.20:00
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can make an alias for date in `.bashrc` by typing `alias date='date +%Y.%m.%d.%R'` and then doing `source .bashrc`, if you want to change `date` default format.

Answer (score 1):

```
date --help
```

and

```
man date
```

both explain how to define a custom format for the output of the date command.

What you're looking for can be found with

```
date +%Y.%m.%d.%R
```

with everything after the + being the string to output with the variables from the current date.